# Connecting to MS Forms connector using Service Principal within logic app

Tags: azure-devops, azure-logic-apps

I am creating a logic app that will trigger when a form request is submitted.
The MS Form connector requires me to sign in. This is acceptable during development, but we have a lot of logic apps and so use DevOps to automate deployment.

With the current connector, after deployment we still have to:

1. manually open the logic app in the portal.
2. connect using authorized credentials.
3. save the logic app.

This manual process completely defeats the point of using DevOps with Logic Apps.
Its a similar issue when using the Outlook connector.

Is there a way to supply server principal credentials to these connectors, so that they are correct at deployment time and require no manual intervention?

Comment: Not get your latest information, is the below answer helpful for you? Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it's not supported to login on MS Forms connector with service principal. Connectors that can use service principal authentication will have "`Connect with Service Principal`" option, like Azure Data explorer. You can give your voice on this [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/287593-logic-apps) to promote this feature.

[image]

API Connections with OAuth authentication, like Office 365 and Microsoft Team connectors etc, require manual consent. Unfortunately, at this point in time, authentication for those cannot be fully automated.

Here is a [ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48290202/run-azure-logic-app-connector-as-service-principal) you can refer to.

Comment: Logic app now supports sign in with managed identity which is the recommended auth type now - both MSI and UMI. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-securing-a-logic-app?tabs=azure-portal#add-authentication-outbound and https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/integrations-on-azure-blog/azure-logic-apps-authenticate-with-managed-identity-for-azure-ad/ba-p/2066254